# CSS vertical sidebar style

Tags: html, css, tags, styles, sidebar

I have a problem with a vertical side bar which has lines inside that must light up when filling in the field.

code:
https://jsfiddle.net/wjfrh5c6/

I need something like that:

[image]

But actually don't work very well:

[image]

this is the css for vertical side bar:

```
.verticalLinePurpleBackground:before{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 3%;
  width: 3%;
  border: 40px solid rgb(107, 5, 247, 0.1);
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
```